# Having issues navigating between frames in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, navigation

I am trying to navigate between pages using a HyperLink Button. However, Visual Studio does not recognize the name of the page that I am trying to navigate to. I am trying to navigate from the main page to a page called `Settings1`, but the following error is produced:

> "The type or namespace name "Settings1" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
private void openSettings_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Settings1));
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Below is a link of my solution space. All I am trying to do is add a Hyperlink Button that the user will click to go from the MainPage to the Settings1 page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWP9Q.png

Comment: Question is a little broad, i try anyway. Did you added a using reference to your `Settings1`? I.e.: in the top most rows of your class add something like `using Namespace.Path.To.Your.Class.Named.Settings1`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add *Settings1* to your project?
Maybe try it with a new instance of your *Settings1* Page like that:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(new Settings1());
```